# RavenDB: PatchRequest to update/merge property that may not exist in document

Tags: c#, .net, database, nosql, ravendb

I have a document with the following domain model:

```
class Entity
{
    ...
    Dictionary<string, string> Settings { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And there's a need to update specified collection. But ***not override*** - ***merge*** with incoming updates. As I need to process thousands of documents in that manner, I choosed the **PatchCommand** for better performance. Got following:

```
new PatchCommandData
{
    Key = upd.EntityId,
    Patches = new[]
    {
        // Foreach incoming Setting remove existing value (if any) and add the new one
        new PatchRequest
        {
            Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
            Name = nameof(Entity.Settings),
            Nested = upd.UpdatedSettings.Keys
                .Select(x => new PatchRequest
                {
                    Type = PatchCommandType.Unset,
                    Name = x
                })
                .ToArray()
                .Union(upd.UpdatedSettings.Keys
                .Select(x => new PatchRequest
                {
                    Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                    Name = x,
                    Value = upd.UpdatedSettings[x]
                })
                .ToList())
                .ToArray(),
            Value = RavenJToken.FromObject(upd.UpdatedSettings)
        }
    }
}
```

This way next update is performed:

```
Before: { Setting1 = "Value1", Setting2 = "Value2" }
Update request: { Setting2 = "NewValue2", Setting3 = "Value3" }
After: { Setting1 = "Value1", Setting2 = "NewValue2", Setting3 = "Value3" }
```

But.. There's always a "but". If there is a *document without Settings property* in  db, provided *patch will raise an error* saying "Cannot modify value from Settings because it was not found".

I can't find any option to switch patch mode to Set vs. Modify on the fly. And there is no option to load all documents, apply the update on application's side and update thousands of documents.
The only reasonable option I can see is to create Dictionary instance for Settings property in the class constructor.

Folks, can you advice some other options?

*P.S. RavenDB version is limited to 3.5*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. You can find the final version below. Actually, the ScriptedPatchCommandData was used. It contains JavaScript body, that Raven will evaluate and execute against documents. Potentially, it isn't the best option from the performance point of view. But nothing critical as it turned out. Hope it may be helpful for someone.

```
const string fieldParameterName = "fieldName";
const string valueParameterName = "value";

var patch = updates
    .Select(update => new ScriptedPatchCommandData
    {
        Key = update.EntityId,
        Patch = new ScriptedPatchRequest
        {
            Script = $"this[{fieldParameterName}] = _.assign({{}}, this[{fieldParameterName}], JSON.parse({valueParameterName}));",
            Values = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { 
                     fieldParameterName,
                     nameof(Entity.Settings)
                },
                {
                    valueParameterName,
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(update.UpdatedSettings)
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .ToList();

return await DocumentStore.AsyncDatabaseCommands.BatchAsync(patch);
```